# Burr distribution in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to calculate the mean and std for burr distribution, but I am not quite sure how to input this. The pdf I am using is: `f(x) = (alpha*gamma*lambda**alpha*x**(gamma-1))/(lambda+x**gamma)**(alpha+1)` from the IFoA Formulae.

I have calculated the parameters to be: alpha = 2.3361635751273977, lambda = 10.596809948869414 and gamma = 0.5 in order to get mean = 500 and std = 600.

Could someone suggest how I should input the data into `scipy.stats.burr` or `scipy.stats.burr12`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`burr12`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.burr12.html#scipy.stats.burr12) here, not `burr`. (The difference is in the sign of the power of x that sits inside another power. Confusingly, it's `burr12` that is usually called simply Burr outside of SciPy, not the thing that SciPy calls `burr`.)

The Burr XII PDF is written in SciPy as `c*d*x**(c-1)*(1+x**c)**(-d-1)` where c, d are positive shape parameters. Your formula

```
(alpha*gamma*lamda**alpha*x**(gamma-1)) / (lamda+x**gamma)**(alpha+1)
```

has lambda in place of 1, so there is some scaling involved. SciPy docs say

> `burr12.pdf(x, c, d, loc, scale)` is identically equivalent to `burr12.pdf(y, c, d) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

So, in order for `lamda+x**gamma` to be a constant multiple of `1 + (x/scale)**gamma`, we need `scale` to be `lamda**(1/gamma)`. The exponents correspond to SciPy notation as `c = gamma` and `d = alpha`. Let's test this:

```
from scipy.stats import burr12
alpha = 2.3361635751273977
lamda = 10.596809948869414
gamma = 0.5

scale = lamda**(1/gamma)
c = gamma
d = alpha
print(burr12.mean(c, d, loc=0, scale=scale))
print(burr12.std(c, d, loc=0, scale=scale))
```

which prints

```
500.0
600.0
```